# Same Code, Different Computers, Different Results. Selenium Not finding web elements

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Made a bot to help post on Craigslist. On my mac and my pc it picks up the web elements fine and can interact with them. On my work pc it can't find them or interact with them at all. I've done it by class, xpath and full xpath and those are pretty much the only 3 options. Furthermore if I have it continue past that, and go on to the next page, it will interact with THE WRONG elements. I have checked the resolution on all the screens so they match and I am at my wits end. I have added the 2 functions that keep breaking. I am running them both in the mainloop under try: except blocks. The postad function...Well it can't find the elements at all and the dropdown, it is clicking on the wrong ones. But to be clear, these work GREAT on my MAC and my PC but when I take it to my works computer it keeps breaking. I made sure everything was updated and installed correctly. I know I can use pyautogui but I was hoping to use just the selenium if possible. But I will try anything, can anyone help this poor smooth brain?

```
def postad(self):
    #The login portion of the bot
    post = self.browser.find_element_by_id("post")
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
    post.click()
    house = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/article/section/form/ul/li[4]/label/span[1]/input")
    house.click()
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
    house2 = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="new-edit"]/div/label/label[2]/input')
    house2.click()
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

def dropDowns(self):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    laundry = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-id-2-button"]/span[2]')
    laundry.click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
    wd_in_unit = self.browser.find_element_by_id('ui-id-12')
    wd_in_unit.click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
    parking = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/article/section/form/div/div/fieldset[1]/div/div[2]/label[3]/span/span[2]')
    parking.click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
    carport = self.browser.find_element_by_id('ui-id-18')
    carport.click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
    bedrooms = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/article/section/form/div/div/fieldset[1]/div/div[2]/label[4]/span/span[2]')
    bedrooms.click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
    if self.choice == 1 :
        onebd = self.browser.find_element_by_id('ui-id-27')
        onebd.click()
    elif self.choice == 2:
        twobd = self.browser.find_element_by_id('ui-id-28')
        twobd.click()
    else:
        threebd = self.browser.find_element_by_id('ui-id-29')
        threebd.click()
    bathrooms = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/article/section/form/div/div/fieldset[1]/div/div[2]/label[5]/span/span[1]')
    bathrooms.click()
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
    if self.choice == 1:
       onebth = self.browser.find_element_by_id('ui-id-38')
       onebth.click()
    else:
        twobth = self.browser.find_element_by_id('ui-id-40')
        twobth.click()
```

Comment: chrome version? os version?

Comment: Chrome 88. OS I am having issues with at work is windows 10

Comment: Thank you @Andi Domi for the edit!! I could not figure out how to get the code in properly!!

Comment: There is a button on your post that looks like `{ }` select your code and then pres that button for format. For a single word code you can use ` (backtic) around the word

Comment: Awesome! I will remember that for next time haha Thank you again!!

Comment: Perhaps the network admins at your work blocked access to Craigslist..

Comment: Good thought Justin. but its able to interact with several other buttons just fine? Would a network admin just block it across the board?

Comment: some web pages may send different HTML for different devices (ie. phone, tablet, desktop) or for different browsers with different settings/extensions - ie, with or without JavaScript. And if page uses JavaScript for buttons and admin/network blocks JavaScript files then buttons may not work.